# What is this language?

Tags: shell

The source file is named "ReadOutputFile.m".

```
function ReadOutputFile(inputFile, outputFile)

SPIT = 2;
R_REGULARITY = 8;

%read input, threshold, and level
spitclip = wavread(inputFile);
spitclip = spitclip*(2^15);

fid = fopen('threshBinary.bin', 'rb', 'native');
thresh = fread(fid, 'int16');
fclose(fid);

fid = fopen('signalLevelBinary.bin', 'rb', 'native');
lvl = fread(fid, 'int16');
fclose(fid);


%get start and stop information from output file
outputNumeric = csvread(outputFile);

starts = outputNumeric(:,1);
stops = outputNumeric(:,2);
types = outputNumeric(:,8);
reasons = outputNumeric(:,9);
regularity = outputNumeric(:,7);

indicesOfSpits = find(types==SPIT);

numEvents = length(starts);

eventGate = zeros(1,length(spitclip));
firstSpits = zeros(1,length(spitclip));
chainedSpits = zeros(1,length(spitclip));

maxVal = 800;

%loop through events and plot spits only
%color code by reason
for n = 1:length(indicesOfSpits)
    i = indicesOfSpits(n);

    if(reasons(i) == R_REGULARITY)
        chainedSpits(starts(i):stops(i)) =  regularity(i)*800;
    else
        firstSpits(starts(i):stops(i)) =  maxVal;
    end
end

plot(spitclip);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(lvl,'r');
plot(thresh, 'y');
plot(firstSpits, 'm');
plot(chainedSpits, 'k');
```

Comment: it looks a bit like a sound parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like Matlab (or the free equivalent octave)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M_(programming_language)

You would wonder, how easy it is to find the programming language.
By just knowing the suffix.

Comment: So, what did you find?  Nothing useful.

Comment: Question was "What is this language?" answer is "M".
Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Except it isn't M.  It's fairly clearly Matlab or something similar.

Comment: Sorry. I just tried to help. I am not greatest programmer, I just thought I could solve your question.